# Can I filter out internal traffic for data that were sent through Measurement Protocol?

Tags: google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

I want to filter out internal traffic from my data so I added the IP addresses and then added a filter which is under "Testing".

The problem is, when I go over Reporting (Realtime Report) to check, I can't add a filter for **Test data filter name** dimension because it shows "No data currently available for this dimension".

Am I correct in assuming that this internal traffic filtering is not available for data sent through Measurement Protocol?

[image]

Comment: Same here. My custom dimensions are there when I view Real-time data but are not 'carried over/available' to real stats X hours later.